# Suppose $A \subseteq P(A)$. Prove that $P(A)\subseteq P(P(A))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am doing some self study before I begin an intro to proofs class. This question is really bugging me, and I think I need someone to look over my proof for it.
The P is for power set, undercase is an element, and capital is a set.

Thank you for any and all help.

Suppose $A \subseteq P(A)$. Prove that $P(A)\subseteq  P(P(A))$

Proof.Suppose A ⊆ P(A), z ∈ Y, Y ∈ X, and X ∈ P(A). Since X ∈ P(A), itfollows that X⊆A. Thus according to A ⊆ P(A), X ⊆ P(A). Since Y∈X, it follows that Y∈ P(A) which is equivalent to Y⊆A. Finally, since z∈Y, we have z∈A. Therefore,P(A)⊆ P(P(A)) QED

Comment: More generally, if $A\subseteq B,$ then $P(A)\subseteq P(B).$

Comment: In other words, the power set of a transitive set is again transitive, since $A$ being transitive means exactly that $A \subseteq P(A)$.

Comment: Can someone explain, what does "$A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ mean?

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA: $X\subseteq Y$ means that every element of $X$ is an element of $Y$. And $\mathcal P(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: Yes dear, I know this definitions. I know, $A\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ but what is this $A\subset \mathcal{P}(A)$. Give an example of set $A$ satisfying this.

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Examples

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA: Then ask *that*. Don't ask "what does this mean", if you know the meaning. $\varnothing$ satisfies this, quite trivially.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly true that if $A\subseteq\wp(A)$ and $z\in Y\in X\in\wp(A)$, then $z\in A$, but this does not show that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(\wp(A))$. To show that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(\wp(A))$, you need to let $X$ be an arbitrary element of $\wp(A)$ and show that $X\in\wp(\wp(A))$. And all of the necessary work is actually there in your argument, along with a fair bit of irrelevant material: if $X\in\wp(A)$, then $X\subseteq A\subseteq\wp(A)$, so $X\subseteq\wp(A)$, and therefore by definition $X\in\wp(\wp(A))$. And that’s it: $X$ was an arbitrary member of $\wp(A)$, so we’ve shown that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(\wp(A))$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot more sense.

Comment: @BobS: You’re welcome.