# making sense of $A\subseteq P(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to make sense of Problem 3.3.4 in Velleman's How to prove it. I don't understand how the following can be a valid expression:
$$A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$$ So $A$ is contained in its power set. What this means is that every element of $A$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ But how can this be? $A$ is a set and an element of A is just a element (not sure how to express this here). However $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a family of sets and an element of this is a set.
So how does this expression make any sense at all?
The solution to the problem is already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729701/suppose-a-subseteq-pa-prove-that-pa-subseteq-ppa), but I am just trying to make sense of the notation not the actual solution.

Comment: Everything is a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In formal set theory there is no special category of objects called "elements". The relation $\subseteq$ is a relation between sets; the object $A$ is a set, and the object $\mathcal P(A)$ is also a set. So $A \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$ is a valid expression (which is sometimes true and sometimes false... but as you say, we're not looking at the actual solution here).

When you write "$A$ is a set and an element of $A$ is just an element (not sure how to express this here)", your unease at the concept of being "just an element" is right on target. There is no such thing in set theory as a thing that is "just an element". In fact, in formal set theory (think set theory following the ZFC axioms), **every object** is a set.

Comment: Dunno what I was thinking there. Fixed. Thanks @spaceisdarkgreen.

Answer (score 4):

Let us analyze the condition $A\subseteq P(A)$.

This is equivalent to $\forall a(a\in A\to a\in P(A))$. So all the elements of $A$ must be sets; $A$ cannot contain any atoms---objects that have no elements, but are not the empty set. (More on atoms below.)

But $a\in P(A)$ means the same as $a\subseteq A$, which means the same as $\forall x(x\in a\to x\in A)$, so finally we have the equivalent condition:
$$\forall x\forall a(x\in a\in A\to x\in A)$$

A set $A$ satisfying this is known as a transitive set. In ZF set theory, all the ordinals are transitive. Here are the first four:
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= \varnothing\\
1 &= \{\varnothing\} &&= \{0\}\\
2 &= \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\} &&=\{0,1\}\\
3 &= \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\} &&=\{0,1,2\}
\end{align*}$$
You can see that $1\in 2$, but also $1\subseteq 2$. Likewise $0$, $1$, and $2$ are elements and also subsets of $3$.

The ordinals are not the only transitive sets, but they form a very important class of transitive sets. Here's another sequence of transitive sets:
$$\begin{align*}
V_0 &= \varnothing\\
V_1 &= P(V_0)\\
V_2 &= P(V_1)\\
\ldots
\end{align*}$$
This also plays an important role in axiomatic set theory.

Now about the atoms. In ZFC, *everything* is a set. This is achieved by various tricks. I say "tricks" because at least two of them seem unintuitive on first encounter. (Later on they seem clever, and eventually entirely natural. At least that was my experience.) The first is the definition of ordinals: with these, we have a workable notion of "nonnegative integer". Is 2, for example *really* the set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$? Probably not a meaningful question; in any case, it can play that role to the hilt.

The ordered pair $(a,b)$ can be defined as the set $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$. Same idea: this definition provides all the properties we need from ordered pairs. With these two tricks, you can now define the integers, the rationals, the reals, etc. etc. as various kinds of sets.

So ZF (also ZFC) doesn't allow atoms. But for some purposes it is nice to allow them. One way to do that is to modify the axioms of ZF slightly, resulting in a system called ZFA. (Or ZFU for those who prefer the Germanic "Urelement" to the English "atom".)